# Extremal graph theory - many copies of $K_r$ imply a copy of $r$-chromatic $H$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I know that it must be a simple consequence of the Kővári–Sós–Turán (and Erdős–Stone) theorem, but I am struggling to formulate a proof: Let $H$ be a fixed-size $r$-chromatic graph. Then there exists $\varepsilon = \varepsilon(H)$ s.t. if $G$ is an $n$-vertex graph that contains $\geq n^{r-\varepsilon}$ copies of $K_r$, it must also contain a (not necessarily induced) copy of $H$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess by copy of $H$ you mean a (not necessarily induced) subgraph? Otherwise, $K_n$ is a counterexample since it does not contain a copy of any $H$ which is not complete.

Comment: indeed, not necessarily induced

Comment: I'm not sure which of these will be helpful to you, but I might start by looking at Theorem 1 in "Graphs with many r-cliques have large complete r-partite subgraphs" by Nikiforov, Lemma 2.1 and Theorem 2.2 in "Hypergraph Turan Problems" by Keevash, and this question together with the answers and comments https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234278/tight-bound-of-turan-number-for-k-1-t-t/246848#246848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from Proposition 2.1 of the paper [Many $T$ copies in $H$-free graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4192) by Alon and Shikhelman.

**Theorem** (Alon and Shikelman)
Let $T$ be a fixed graph with $t$ vertices.  Then $ex(n,T,H)=\Omega(n^t)$ if and only if $H$ is not a subgraph of a blow-up of $T$.  Otherwise, $ex(n,T,H) \le n^{t-\varepsilon(T,H)}$ for some $\varepsilon(T,H) > 0$.

Here, $ex(n,T,H)$ is the maximum number of copies of $T$ in an $n$-vertex $H$-free graph.

To derive your result, we apply Alon-Shikelman with $T=K_r$ and $H$ a fixed $r$-chromatic graph.  Thus, $H$ is a subgraph of a blow-up of $K_r$.  So, we may choose $\varepsilon(H)$ to be any positive constant less than $\varepsilon(K_r, H)$.

Comment: This is not quite right: the fact that $G$ has $n^{r-\varepsilon}$ copies of $K_r$ does not imply that at most $O(n^\varepsilon)$ $r$-subsets are not cliques, as the $-\varepsilon$ is in the exponent, thus $n^{r-\varepsilon} + x = \Theta(n^r)$ gives $x \approx n^{r-\varepsilon} \cdot (n^\varepsilon - 1)$ $r$-subsets which are not cliques.

Comment: You're right.  I edited the answer.  It follows from a result of Alon and Shikhelman.

Comment: Indeed, thanks!